# Sending form data to an server using multer

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having some trouble sending form data to my Node.js server. I'm closely following the examples in the readme, but the result is either an empty object or undefined.

This is my server code:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer()

app.post('/', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.send("Hello from the server!")
})

app.listen(3000)
```

I'm testing this by running the following in the Chrome console:

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest()
xml.open("POST", "/")
var fd = new FormData()
fd.append("foo", "bar")
xml.setRequestHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=200")
xml.send(fd)
```

I don't know how to get the correct boundary for the `setRequestHeader` call, so I just put 200. When I send this, the server prints `{}`. It prints `undefined` without the `setRequestHeader` call. `xml.responseText` is the expected string `Hello from the server!`.

Comment: Why do you use Chrome console is testing the API? It's very hard. Maybe for testing you should use Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) or sth similar